# @FETCH_STATUS as a Variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem regarding using a stored procedure to build a view for a database. The stored procedure will use a cursor to cycle through child databases that are in a parent database (I have a company database, that holds facility database names in it). The stored procedure will get the facilities and then append the table to those databases.

For example:

```
OPEN cur_facdb

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_facdb INTO @fac_dw_db_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    SET @sql_command = "CREATE VIEW dbo.BMK_LOCAL_FACILITY_VW 
                        AS 
                             SELECT * 
                             FROM " + @fac_dw_db_name + " .dbo.BMK_FACILITY"

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_facdb INTO @fac_dw_db_name
END

CLOSE cur_facdb
DEALLOCATE cur_facdb
```

This right now will get me a list of 5 or 6 facilities that look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM facility_aaaa.dbo.BMK_FACILITY
SELECT * FROM facility_aaab.dbo.BMK_FACILITY
SELECT * FROM facility_aaac.dbo.BMK_FACILITY
```

Etc....

The problem is that I need to append at the end of each select statement `UNION ALL`, of course, all but the last record that is produced.

Now having said all of that, is there a way to dump the `@FETCH_STATUS` into a variable, and then append it to the statement like so:

```
SET @sql_command = "CREATE VIEW dbo.BMK_LOCAL_FACILITY_VW AS 
SELECT * FROM " + @fac_dw_db_name + " .dbo.BMK_FACILITY  
*CASE WHEN @Fetch_Variable = 0 THEN 'UNION ALL' ELSE '' END*
"
```

The reason I can't build a standard view and hard code the facilities is because facilities can be dropped and added monthly, so I am trying to dynamically create this view every month.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Not related to your question per se but your should wrap  @fac_dw_db_name in the QUOTENAME() function to protect against SQL Injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `union all` at the beginning, then `stuff()` the `create view` in place of the first `union all`.  Like this:

```
declare @tbl table (name varchar(100))

insert into @tbl values ('facility_aaaa'),('facility_aaab'),('facility_aaac')

declare @sql varchar(max), @t varchar(100), @crlf char(2) = char(13) + char(10)

declare cr cursor local for
  select name
  from   @tbl
  order by name

set @sql = ''

open cr
fetch next from cr into @t

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  set @sql = @sql + 'union all' + @crlf + 'select * from ' + @t + '.dbo.BMK_FACILITY' + @crlf
  fetch next from cr into @t
end

close cr
deallocate cr

set @sql = stuff(@sql, 1, 9, 'create view dbo.BMK_LOCAL_FACILITY_VW AS')

print @sql
```

Which prints this:

```
create view dbo.BMK_LOCAL_FACILITY_VW AS
select * from facility_aaaa.dbo.BMK_FACILITY
union all
select * from facility_aaab.dbo.BMK_FACILITY
union all
select * from facility_aaac.dbo.BMK_FACILITY
```

Alternatively, you can accomplish the same thing and use a `case` statement to add `union all` to all but the last record.  Add a new column to your cursor query `rn = row_number() over (order by name desc)` and then reverse sort it `order by rn desc`.  You get a descending integer, where `rn` will equal `1` on the last record.  Like this:

```
declare @tbl table (name varchar(100))

insert into @tbl values ('facility_aaaa'),('facility_aaab'),('facility_aaac')

declare @sql varchar(max), @t varchar(100), @crlf char(2) = char(13) + char(10), @rn int

declare cr cursor local for
  select name, rn = row_number() over (order by name desc)
  from   @tbl
  order by rn desc

set @sql = 'create view dbo.BMK_LOCAL_FACILITY_VW AS' + @crlf

open cr
fetch next from cr into @t, @rn

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  set @sql = @sql + 'select * from ' + @t + '.dbo.BMK_FACILITY' + @crlf + case when @rn > 1 then 'union all' + @crlf else '' end
  fetch next from cr into @t, @rn
end

close cr
deallocate cr

print @sql
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dale, first time running into the STUFF function. Will definitely be using it in the future.

Comment: And James, that was brilliant. And simple. Thank you also.